# C# function calling to cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am not able to call a function in my CSHTML page.

in my cshtml page script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
        //var sLoggedInUser = <%# GetSession_LoggedInIdUser() %>;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("dom");

            var sLoggedInUser = PageMethods.GetSession_LoggedInUserName();          

            alert(sLoggedInUser);
        });


        function btnClick() {
            alert("btn click");
        }

    </script>
```

dom is alerted, button click function work well, but get no value of sLoggedInUser.
In my cs page:

```
 protected string GetSession_LoggedInUserName()
        {
            SessionConfiguration Obj_Configuration = (SessionConfiguration)Session["Configuration"];
            return Obj_Configuration.LoggedInUserName;
        }
```

I also try with : `var sLoggedInUser = <%= PageMethods.GetSession_LoggedInUserName() %>` // `var sLoggedInUser = GetSession_LoggedInUserName()`

Comment: Maybe have to be static?

Answer (score 2):

```
var sLoggedInUser = PageMethods.GetSession_LoggedInUserName();
```

won't work because you can't call a server side method directly from javascript.

```
var sLoggedInUser = <%= PageMethods.GetSession_LoggedInUserName() %>
```

is closer, but will output javascript like

```
var sLoggedInUser = John Smith
```

but that's not valid javascript because the string isn't enclosed in quotes.  However, you can't just rely on

```
var sLoggedInUser = '<%= PageMethods.GetSession_LoggedInUserName() %>'
```

because you may have a user with a name like Paddy O'Brien, which would terminate the string too early with the apostrophe in the name (and switching to single quotes isn't really much safer).  There can also be other characters that you might need to worry about so you should use a function to convert the string to Json.  I'm not sure what that is because I'm used to using Razor with the helper functions, but if you have access to the helpers then it would be something like

```
var sLoggedInUser = <%= Html.Json(PageMethods.GetSession_LoggedInUserName())%>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function public static instead of protected

```
public static string GetSession_LoggedInUserName()
{
        SessionConfiguration Obj_Configuration = (SessionConfiguration)Session["Configuration"];
        return Obj_Configuration.LoggedInUserName;
}
```

and Call in cshtml like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var sLoggedInUser = '@PageMethods.GetSession_LoggedInUserName()'
        alert(sLoggedInUser);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Method should be like this, `static` and a `WebMethod`

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSession_LoggedInUserName()
{
 ...
}
```